# Give a Wordpress User Only rights to his clients and report

Tags: wordpress, civireport, permissions

first of all i want to say CiviCRM is a wonderful!!

I have a CiviCRM installation with a lot of clients in it. Also there are 20 users. I use a Wordpress bases installation of CiviCRM. And each user has his own report.

Now all the users can see all the reports, and can find all the sales of other users and so on..

Is there a way to give for example User_A only rights to see:
- The report of User_A 
- The search results only from what has to do with User_A

The User_A has a Custom Field, with i filter on in the report to see.

I hope someone can give a good solution for this problem.

With Kind Regards,
Mark

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  This looks like a good question.  You could help to improve it by including the versions of CiviCRM and WordPress that you are using.  This may affect the answers given.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get what you need by using ACLs (Administer>Users & Permissions>Permissions (Access Control)). This will allow you to create roles, assign users to those roles and create ACLs to provide permissions for certain actions to those roles. You can assign access permissions on reports to specific roles also.

You will need to create some Access Control groups for your users and their clients to manage your ACLs. It will take a bit of planning but should be doable.

You should also assign your users a role in WordPress and assign them permissions on the CMS level.

There are details here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/